# How to run a jupyter notebook at a particular folder in docker

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I have set up jupyter notebook in the correct port in docker , everytime I need to upload data into the notebook and do analysis , is there anyway I can get up my jupyter file location to a particular file ,keeping in mind I'm using docker.

Answer (score 0):

You need to volume your folder to the Docker container. An example that you use `jupyter/all-spark-notebook` image, so you can run:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888  -p 4040:4040 -v your-path:/home/jovyan/workspace jupyter/all-spark-notebook
```

Update `your-path` to the path contains your notebooks

Comment: Thanks man, do you know any youTube videos or blogs that I can follow , to run posgres and other containers for Data analytics , like how we can connect to external databases, etc